# Negative values in the data not showing in highcharts linechart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In my linecharts I had passed negative values in the data array, and those are not showing in the linecharts. What would be the problem.

When I am creating the data array I am just casting the values into a float using parseFloat.

If the data array is like this:

```
[-1.800000000,2.57,-3.72,7.82,-5.0]
```

The chart is only showing for positive values not for negative values like below.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure that the property -

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,//<----Remove
    /*max: 100,*/
    title: {
        text: this.yAxisTitle,
        align: 'low'
    }
}
```